# Use c# to run 2 pyhon.exe

Tags: c#, python, process, com

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    doPython("python", "C:\\Users\\COM\\Desktop\\test_files\\data_cleaning.py");
    textBox1.Text = "Data Cleaning...";
   }
   private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    doPython("python", "C:\\Users\\COM\\Desktop\\test_files\\indu.py");
    textBox1.Text = "Deep learning processing...";
   }
   private static void doPython(string StartFileName, string StartFileArg) {
    Process CmdProcess = new Process();
    CmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = StartFileName; //  
    CmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = StartFileArg; //  
    CmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //   
    CmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; //   
    CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //   
    CmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //
    CmdProcess.Start();
    CmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    CmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    CmdProcess.WaitForExit();
    CmdProcess.Close();
   }
```

I want to use c# to run 2 pythons, so I designed 2 buttons, and let them run different python files, but I found, only the first python file work, the second one can not go into `doPython`, how to figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the first button works, executing the first file, my thoughts would be that you may be dealing with one of the following issues:

1. The Python file at `C:\\Users\\COM\\Desktop\\test_files\\indu.py` does not exist. If this is case, make sure the path to the file is correct, or make sure the file exists at that path.
2. The button event handler was not set up properly. If this is the case, re-instantiate the button event handler, using the same code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I checked, the C:\\Users\\COM\\Desktop\\test_files\\indu.py exist, and event handler works, and I even rexisted,,,but it is still don't work, there is no error here, just,,,no answer

Comment: Maybe this link will help: https://medium.com/emoney-engineering/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5